# arrastrar y soltar carpeta con archivos javascript

Tags: javascript

hola quisiera saber si es posible capturar los archivos de una carpeta q arrastre en mi zona destinada para ello; tengo un dropzone donde suelto archivos el problema es q quiero la posibilidad de arrastrar una carpeta y que capture los archivos que se encuentran dentro de ella hasta el momento tengo algo asi pero solo logro imprimir la carpeta no lo q tiene dentro:

```
  const draggableFileArea = document.getElementById("dropzone");
  draggableFileArea.addEventListener('dragover' , e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
  })
  draggableFileArea.addEventListener('drop' , e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.files
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      console.log(files[i]);
    }
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.files)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es cambiar `e.dataTransfer.files` por `e.dataTransfer.items` para poder usar la función [webkitGetAsEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry), la cual devuelve un objeto con funciones necesarias para determinar si es una carpeta o no, y como recorrer los archivos dentro de ella.

Luego hay que crear una función `procesarArchivo` para operar como quieras con el/los archivos, está función se llamará recursivamente cuando sea necesario.

```
draggableFileArea.addEventListener('drop' , e =>{
  e.preventDefault();

  const files = e.dataTransfer.items;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const item = files[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (item) procesarArchivo(item);
  }
});
  
function procesarArchivo(item){
  if (item.isFile) {
      item.file(file => {
          console.log(file);  //Aquí debes procesar uno a uno los archivos
      });
  }
  else if(item.isDirectory){
     const dirReader = item.createReader();
     dirReader.readEntries((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => { //recorre cada entrada y vuelve a llamar recursivamente a procesarArchivo para que determine si la entrada es un archivo o una subcarpeta
          procesarArchivo(entry); 
        });
     });
  }
```

Comment: vale lo voy a probar y te comento gracias